# Header files are included, but still cannot call the functions

Tags: ubuntu, c++

I'm trying to write a plotting program with c++ under ubuntu12.04. OpenGL is applicated in my code(cc.cpp). I have included the necessary header files, but the openGL function still cannot be used.

This is the include codes.

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
```

when I run `g++ cc.cpp` in terminal, terminal displays this:

```
/tmp/ccsiISvK.o: In function `initGL()':
cc.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `glOrtho'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `glGetError'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `gluErrorString'
/tmp/ccsiISvK.o: In function `render()':
cc.cpp:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `glClear'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `glBegin'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `glColor3f'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x18b): undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `glEnd'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
/tmp/ccsiISvK.o: In function `runMainLoop(int)':
cc.cpp:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `glutTimerFunc'
/tmp/ccsiISvK.o: In function `main':
cc.cpp:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `glutInit'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `glutInitContextVersion'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x248): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x29b): undefined reference to `glutTimerFunc'
cc.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone have a solution for this? I will appreciate that!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! We are a site of professionals for computer hardware/software problems. Programming falls out of our scope as defined in the FAQ, but I have voted to move this to Stackoverflow, the site for programmers. Please don't post there as well, this question will move naturally

Comment: The header files are of no concern whatsoever to the *linker*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add flags to `g++` to include the necessary libraries with the `-l` option.
It might be something like how it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568067/using-gcc-mingw-to-compile-opengl-on-windows) or [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/157014-Compiling-with-gcc)

Try this -

`g++ cc.cpp -lGL -lglut`